# Is there a way to invoke route manually in ServiceStack, using just a string that would otherwise be its URL?

Tags: c#, servicestack

I have a DTO like this in ServiceStack

```
[Route("/skillslist/{TaskTypeId*}", WebMethods.Get)]
public class GetSkillsList : IReturn<List<SkillDto>>
{
    public long? TaskTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

and a method on a service like this

```
public List<SkillDto> Get(GetSkillsList request){...}
```

Inside another unrelated method (on another service in the same assembly, same host), I want to trigger the above route and get its result, when i only have a ready route string like "/skillslist/5".

Could anyone please tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Services in ServiceStack are essentially just normal auto-wired classes (with the current RequestContext injected). From inside any Service you can all another service using `base.ResolveService<TService>`, e.g:

```
public object Any(AnotherRequest request)
{
    using (var service = base.ResolveService<GetSkillsService>())
    {
        List<SkillDto> results = service.Get(new GetSkillsList { ... });
    }
}
```

Note: this is just a standard C# method call, i.e. it just resolves the Service from the IOC and executes it, so there's no performance penalty as it doesn't do any HTTP or DTO de/serialization, etc.

And from outside of ServiceStack (e.g. in MVC) you can call a Service with [AppHostBase.ResolveService](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Mvc-integration#calling-servicestack-services-from-mvc-controllers), e.g:

```
using (var service = AppHostBase.ResolveService<GetSkillsService>(HttpContext.Current))
{
    List<SkillDto> results = service.Get(new GetSkillsList { ... });
}
```

### Executing a service with just the path info

1) Get the `IRestPath` with:

```
var controller = EndpointHost.Config.ServiceController;
var restPath = controller.GetRestPathForRequest("GET","/skillslist/5");
```

2) Create a new instance with:

```
var queryString = new Dictionary<string,string>();
var request = restPath.CreateRequest("/skillslist/5", queryString, null);
```

3) Then execute it with:

```
var response = controller.Execute(request, base.RequestContext);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that gives me a nudge in the right direction. I'm aware of the two ways described, but my situation is different. As i said - I want to call a sibling service without knowing anything about it - no DTO Type, no Service Type - with just the URL string. From what I can see, appHost.ExecuteService(someDto); does the second half of what I want to do. Now I’m trying to figure out how to manually resolve my path string into a DTO.

Comment: @IvanKoshelew Not that I've tried it, but you can get the `IRestPath` with `var restPath = EndpointHost.Config.ServiceController. GetRestPathForRequest("GET","/skillslist/5");`. Create a new instance with `var request = restPath.CreateRequest("/skillslist/5", new Dictionary<string,string>(), null);` and then execute it with `var response = EndpointHost.Config.ServiceController.Execute(request, base.RequestContext)`;